# C# Error 401 - Invalid username or password

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services, rest, http-status-code-401

I'm trying to make requests to an API.
When I made the request using postman, it works. But in c#, it doesn't, it returns Error 401.
I checked and login and password are right.
Can anyone help me?

---

**Code:**

```
public JsonResult Test()
{
    var document = new HtmlAgilityPack.HtmlDocument();

    var password = CalculateMD5Hash("******");

    var httpRequest =(HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(string.Format("https://api.akna.com.br/emkt/int/integracao.php?User={0}&Pass={1}&XML={2}",
    "mail@mail.com",
     password,
    @"<main>
    <emkt trans='19.10'>
    <datainicial>2016-07-01 10:00:00</datainicial>
    <datafinal>2016-07-02 10:00:00</datafinal>
    </emkt>
    </main>"));

    httpRequest.Method = "POST";
    httpRequest.ContentType = "application/x-www-form-urlencoded";

    try
    {
    var httpWebResponse = (HttpWebResponse)httpRequest.GetResponse();

    var responseStream = httpWebResponse.GetResponseStream();

    if (responseStream != null)
    {
     var sr = new StreamReader(responseStream, Encoding.Default);
     document.LoadHtml(sr.ReadToEnd());
   }

   return Json(new { StatusCode = 200 }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
   }
  catch (Exception ex)
  {
  return Json(new { StatusCode = 500, Erro = ex.Message }, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
 }
 }
```

Comment: Well if it works via Postman and doesn't work via C#, then perhaps you should inspect the network traffic with a tool like Fiddler and see what the difference is!

Comment: I never used Fiddler, I downloaded it, but my request only works in postman. The two requests seem to be identical. Postman request: [link](http://imgur.com/12sbyoX)  Fiddler request: [link](http://imgur.com/g5oYFC6). Do you know what is the problem? Thanks!

Comment: Look at the raw request. Compare them closely. Their service doesn't care what client you use, whether it's .NET or Fiddler or a CURL command. So long as it sees the request in the right format it should work. That's why you need to spot the difference.

Comment: Remember that you can use postman to convert the request to C# code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was the encoding of the parameters. It solved the problem: http://rest.elkstein.org/2008/02/using-rest-in-c-sharp.html